# getting warning must be used from main thread in Xcode 11.2 and app crashed, not getting warning in Xcode 10.2

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I opened Project in Xcode 10.2 I **did not get any warning messages like "must be used from main thread"**

But When I opened same Project in Xcode 11.2 I **get warning messages like "must be used from main thread" and app crashed**.

This thing (must be used from main thread) happens many place on different controller in Xcode 11.2 (not in Xcode 10.2)

```
[self.viewIndicator stopAnimating];
```

I also got warning message "must be used from main thread" when I stopped UIActivityIndicatorView.

I do not understand why did this happen?.

My Project run absolutely fine in Xcode 10.2 but in Xcode 11.2 my Project get warning messages like "must be used from main thread" and app crashed**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Apple documentation -

> Updating UI on a thread other than the main thread is a common mistake that can result in missed UI updates, visual defects, data corruptions, and crashes.

You can fix it by adding the code for UI changes to run on the Main Thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Here you can add some UI work
});
```

Comment: I knew this but,
When I run project in Xcode 11.2, I get warning message and app crashes.

in Xcode 10.2 at same place I did not get any warning messages and app does not crash.

Comment: I would guess that Apple is now more strict about it and in later Xcode versions, they enforce it so developers won't make this mistake.

Comment: May be you are right, but I face this same things in Xcode 10.1 and getting warning messages like "must be used from main thread" but, in Xcode 10.2 I did not get any warning messages.

Comment: whenever i needed I used dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Here you can add some UI work
}); to update UI on main thread

Answer (score 0):

As Said in the above answer following the release of IOS 13 apple has been strict about the "UI Updates happening on the main thread." Therefore all the places that you will be updating your UI in other threads will give you warnings/crashes . Something to note is that this will happen if the device follows IOS 13 as well( not all cases but i came accross this) so it is better that you update all the places that you do not follow this synatx .

In "previos Versions of `Xcode` you will not come accross this as it did not check it so thoroughly , how ever in Xcode 11 /IOS 13 you will face this issue almost evereytime , you can use this to make it run from the main thread .

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(methodName) withObject:(nil) waitUntilDone:(YES)];
```